# How To Add JSLink For Calendar Event

Tags: sharepoint-2013

I'm using sharepoint 2013 and i want to utilize the client side rendering feature using JSLink, when editing the web part for the calendar new event, in the "miscellaneous" there is no field for JSLink, how to modify the render for new event using JSLink ?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible. See [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/ed3c07fd-a873-483a-8df0-dbdc99d62402/jslink-does-not-work-on-column-in-a-calendar-list?forum=sharepointdevelopment) discussion.

*After about an hour's worth of research I found the problem. Microsoft specifically targets the Invalid, Event, and Survey list types to ignore client rendering. Unless you create your own webpart you will not ever be able to use any of the JSLink properties for these list types. Maybe somebody at Microsoft can explain themselves here as to why they would have crippled us like that or what a proper approach for this common problem would be. Yet another reason the Calendar is a piece of garbage in SharePoint 2013!*

Also [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/db240f08-470d-4693-86a6-5baf95b06ee1/js-link-in-calender-view?forum=sharepointdevelopment) answer:

*There is no OOTB way to attach Javascript with calendar view (no property exposed for that listview). For a workaround you can create your own JQUERY or JAVASCRIPT and add on calendar view page by adding the reference in Content Editor Webpart on that page.,*

However I have a quick but dirty solution. Add a SriptEditor to yout page, below the calendar and insert:

```
var oldEditLink = EditLink2;
EditLink2 = function(a,b,c){

if (isNaN(b) && b.substring(0,3) == "WPQ"){
    var itemId = a.getAttribute("href").split("=")[1];

   // do what you want to do
   return false;
}
oldEditLink(a,b,c);
```

}